# How to identify full sentences in a scraped web page with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nlp, text-processing

I am currently working on a school project and try to analyze articles on different web pages. With the help of BeautifulSoup I was able to clean out all code parts out of the content.

Now, I want to clean out the other parts like menus, sitemap entries, buttons etc. to only have full sentences as text from the web page. Do you know how I am able to identify full sentences like

```
The sequel trilogy is the third installment of films of the Star Wars saga to be produced.
```

but to clean out words that do not make sense as a group like a navigation

```
Explore Trending Navigation About Us Community
```

I already used the tokenization of words, but this is usually used to clean words in the sense of singular / plural, endings, stop words and so on. I want to have the text like it was written but without the "noise".

I hope I was able to describe my problem in an understandable way.

Comment: create a `set` with words you want to blacklist, then check if the word is in the `set` and skip printing it

Comment: @MendelG Unfortunately, the words always change because it should be a generic solution to get text as sentences from different web pages (not known by run time).

Comment: You can try looking for tags so that you don't take text from tags where text you need wouldn't be located or take text from tags where text may be located so for example take text only from paragraph and heading tags. Additionally, separately check each group of tags where you take text from by checking if the first letter is capital and it ends with a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** A **quick** rule based solution: [language-tool](https://pypi.org/project/language-tool-python/)
This library allows you to make to detect grammar errors and spelling mistakes

Example Usage:

```
import language_tool_python
tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US')
text = 'A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he Galaxy'
matches = tool.check(text)
len(matches)
2
```

Check out some Match object attributes:

```
matches[0].ruleId, matches[0].replacements # ('EN_A_VS_AN', ['an'])
('EN_A_VS_AN', ['an'])
matches[1].ruleId, matches[1].replacements
('TOT_HE', ['to the'])
```

Print a Match object:

```
print(matches[1])

Line 1, column 51, Rule ID: TOT_HE[1]
Message: Did you mean 'to the'?
Suggestion: to the
```

**2** If this doesn't work for you, try **deep learning** based solutions. You will have to train a **text classification** model for **sentence correctness**. You can train your model on  **Corpus of Linguistic Acceptability (CoLA)** dataset as explained in [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/sentence-correctness-classifier-using-transfer-learning-with-huggingface-bert-8884795ba5ca) for BERT. The [colab-notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13ErkLg5FZHIbnUGZRkKlL-9WNCNQPIow) may require some debugging. [Another tutorial.](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-use-bert-transformer-for-grammar-checking/)

**3.** An even better solution would be to modify the T5 based [sentence doctor](https://huggingface.co/flexudy/t5-base-multi-sentence-doctor). It attempts to correct the errors or mistakes found in sentences. You just need to know whether a sentence is correct or not, so you will have to modify the last layer of this model and then fine-tune. GPU memory might be a restriction as T5 is huge.